# Using tr to place the words of a file in order so that each line contains 1 word in order of appearence and without spaces

Tags: special-characters, tr

I want to remove the special characters of a text files for that I found the following command

```
tr -d '[:punct:]' < file.txt
```

But, I also want to change the format of the file so that each line contains 1 word, exemple:

Hello my name is steven.

would ouput :

Hello
my
name
is
Steven

Answer (score 0):

You can replace whitespace by newlines, squeezing each repeat into a single replacement (the `-s` may not be necessary, depending on the structure of whitespace in your file):

```
tr -d '[:punct:]' < file.txt  | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, if I have a word lets say its readme.txt, the command gets rid of the . and adds a newline so my output is: readme \newline txt what if I wanted to get the readmetxt all together?

Comment: @gabriel I have amended the answer to handle the case of "in word" punctuation characters - for that case, doing the replacement in two steps (via a pipe) should work